# Line Chart (Dual-Y) x-axis data in reverse order

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I am working on a dual-y axis line chart and am trying to show the data in x axis in reverse order.

The direction attribute dont seem to be working for me.

original - **https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/**
here is my change - **https://jsfiddle.net/3m8vjows/**

I have tried to give the direction to the x axis as below. But is not working.

```
  var materialOptions = {
    chart: {
      title: 'Average Temperatures and Daylight in Iceland Throughout the Year'
    },
    width: 900,
    height: 500,
    series: {
      // Gives each series an axis name that matches the Y-axis below.
      0: {axis: 'Temps'},
      1: {axis: 'Daylight'}
    },
    axes: {
      // Adds labels to each axis; they don't have to match the axis names.
      y: {
        Temps: {label: 'Temps (Celsius)'},
        Daylight: {label: 'Daylight'}
      },
    x:{direction:'-1'}
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following config option is not supported by *material* charts

```
{hAxis,vAxis,hAxes.*,vAxes.*}.direction
```

there are several options *material* charts do not support,
see --> [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)

*material* = `google.charts.Line` & `packages: ['line']`

*classic* = `google.visualization.LineChart` & `packages: ['corechart']`

---

there is an option you can use to make *classic* charts look **similar** to *material*

```
theme: 'material'
```

if you choose to use *classic* instead...

Comment: Thanks. I think I mixed options.